# what do the properties of a grunt.initConfig configObject represent?

Tags: gruntjs

Here's one property from a gruntfile I'm reviewing:

```
    'uglify': {
        'build': {
            'files': {
                '<%= config.files.js_app_min %>': '<%= config.files.js_app_min %>'
            }
        }
    },
```

Would 'uglify' represent a grunt task in this scenario?  Does the subobject under the top level object simply represent a task-specific configuration object?

Answer (score 0):

The task name base on developer.
read [Creating plugins](http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins) and [Creating tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks).

For example [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/blob/master/tasks/copy.js) is a simple plugin. Let's see its code.

the config of a plugin in grunt.initConfig is base on this code:
`grunt.registerMultiTask('copy', 'Copy files.', function() {`.

The task name which developer register like `copy` will be the configObject in  grunt.initConfig.

In effect, the task name can named whatever you want. It's more like a conventional way we develop a plugin

Comment: thanks!  I have a gruntfile.js config file included in a file that I brought down from source control.  is there a way I can do a backwards trace to find the actual plugin that maps to the registered taskname in gruntfile.js?